# How to disable the suggested videos displayed over the ongoing video that come in YouTube near the end of the ongoing video?

Tags: video, youtube

I find it annoying since these suggested videos just pop up and cover the screen of the current video that I am watching.

Comment: Is this for YouTube.com, or using the YouTube script/tag on your own site?

Comment: it's for youtube.com

Comment: Then Leo's suggest is the best one.  There may be plugins that tweak YouTube's behavior, but YT likes to change their programming....

Answer (score 1):

You can use adblockers/scriptblockers for that. It's not possible via YouTube's built-in features.